# Constrained minimization: spring system

Tags: convex-optimization, physics

I'm doing a game with somewhat realistic physics, and I have a system of springs, for this you can imagine a table supported by >=3 springs, if necessary we can assume all spring have the same stiffness.

[Visual example of table with springs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ogPq.png)

What I know:

- Centre of mass of the table (CoM)
- Mass of the table (M)
- Table rotation (Rx/Ry)
- Springs displacement (X)
- Springs stiffness (K)
- Springs position (Px/Py)

What I need:

- Mass or load supported by each spring (Fn)

With some investigation I made some constraints, correct me if I'm wrong (please note that I'm not a mathematician neither physicist):

$$
M * 9.81= F_1+F_2+...F_n
$$
Spring equation:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n X_n = \frac{F_1}{K_1}+\frac{F_n}{K_n}+...\frac{F_n}{K_n}
$$
Torque forces in equilibrium in x/y:
$$
\sin(Rx_1)F_1Px_1 + \sin(Rx_2)F_2Px_2 + \dots + \sin(Rx_n)F_nPx_n = CoM_X
$$
$$
\sin(Ry_1)F_1Py_1 + \sin(Ry_2)F_2Py_2 + \dots + \sin(Ry_n)F_nPy_n = CoM_Y
$$

I found online a way to solve a problem when I have 4+ springs, so I tried to do a constrained minimization using lagrange multipliers, using the function f = sum((Fn - Mu)^2). Where Mu is the mass average.

Will this work? I tried to make some calculations and I got weird values
I not used to this kind of problem, so I'm taking the right direction?

Comment: Would you furnish us a kind of graphical setup to clarify ideas?

Comment: @Cesareo I changed the post and added a image to show an example of a table supported by 4 springs in equilibrium.